# Javascript Replace Text With HTML

Tags: javascript, html, replace

I'm doing some javascript replacement testing and have hit a wall.

The below code will replace the E10 but leave E0 alone while the E10 replacement line is present. I wish to eventually build this all the way up to E100 and then do the same for D0-100, C0-100, all the way to A and eventually S. I have pre-made graphics for all of it (Re-colored for each letter). However I can't seem to get it to function properly.

Anyone know how to make it replace each one and not just whichever one is loaded last?

```
<body onload="myFunction()">

E50  E30  E10 <br>

E60  E40  E0

</body>


<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/E0/g, '<img src="http://s31.postimg.org/5riz5vn0b/Zero.png"/>');
}
</script>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/E10/g, '<img src="http://s31.postimg.org/6wm82qo8r/ten.png"/>');
}
</script>
```

Any and all help would be appreciated.

Comment: You redeclare your `myFunction` so the first one gets removed and is never executed.

Comment: I was about to say that :)

Comment: To generalize the lesson here: `<script>` blocks do not have any "scope". All `<script>` blocks loaded by the page are basically concatenated into one big script file.

Comment: Yes, I see that now. Thank you, I learned a great deal from this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the function once and add both replaces in it: https://jsfiddle.net/rx3x75rk/

```
function myFunction() {
    document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/E0/g, '<img src="http://s31.postimg.org/5riz5vn0b/Zero.png"/>');
    document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/E10/g, '<img src="http://s31.postimg.org/6wm82qo8r/ten.png"/>');
}
```

Comment: Quick thing, any way to have this exclude making changes to input fields? It is currently effecting the entire site, which is great. I just didn't think about it effecting textareas. xD

Comment: @ChristopherThompson yes, but I would need some samples of what you want to change